# Virtual Pages in Users Flow report in analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way I can remove virtual pages from my Users Flow report in analytics?

Comment: Or better yet, could I filter for just virtual (or ghost) pages throughout my analytics?

Comment: I assume you mean Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

For GA any pageview is pageview. It doesn't know if it is real or virtual. The only solution to your problem is creating a hit-level custom-dimension and setting its value (virtual/real) for each pageview sent.

Important thing here - it will work only for future data - you cannot change (most of the) data in GA retrospectively.